# Get Data of not visible items from recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want a help from you guys can anybody solve this problem i am trying to insert three rows into mysql table but right here only two rows are visible and third on get visible on scrolling down so when i click submit it gets me an error it inserts 2 visible rows on the screen and throws a null pointer expection on the 3 row that is not visible can some one help me to get the data from the view that is not visible i know its recyclerview and it re uses the view i know the mechanism i just want the solution from some that so that the 3 row that is not visible can get added successfully to the database

Here is an image for that :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPBqn.jpg

My recyclerview adapter code:

```
public class MyAdapterClosing extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterClosing.myViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<DataofClosing> student;

    public MyAdapterClosing(Context context, List<DataofClosing> student){
        this.context = context;
        this.student = student;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layoutclosing,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DataofClosing s = student.get(position);
        holder.brand.setText(s.Brandname);



    }


    public void updateList(List<RecyclerviewWholesale> student)
    {
        student = student;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addItem(int position, DataofClosing stud)
    {
        student.add(position, stud);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        student.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, student.size());
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return student.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }



    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView brand;
        EditText qts,pts,nip,ml90;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            brand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand);
            qts = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.qts);
            pts = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pts);
            nip = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nip);
            ml90 = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ml90);

            String qtss = qts.getText().toString();
            String ptss = pts.getText().toString();
            String nipp = nip.getText().toString();
            String ml900 = ml90.getText().toString();

            DataofClosing dataofClosing = new DataofClosing();
            dataofClosing.qts = qtss;
            dataofClosing.pts = ptss;
            dataofClosing.nip = nipp;
            dataofClosing.ml90 = ml900;



        }
    }

}
```

Inserting code in the main activity is:

```
class Insertclosing extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                rcData = data.get(i);
                View view1 = closingService.getChildAt(i);
                EditText nameEditText = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.qts);
                String name = nameEditText.getText().toString();
                EditText ptss = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.pts);
                String pts = ptss.getText().toString();
                EditText nipp = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.nip);
                String nip = nipp.getText().toString();
                EditText ml900 = (EditText) view1.findViewById(R.id.ml90);
                String ml90 = ml900.getText().toString();
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("brand", rcData.Brandname));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("discount",pts));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ammount",nip ));


                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insert_product_sales,
                        "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                    /*runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            Toast.makeText(ChangeAddress.this, "Order Placed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });*/
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                Toast.makeText(closing.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });               // failed to create product
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

             Toast.makeText(closing.this, "Closing added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: To have the RecyclerView, you need to have all your data in `List<DataofClosing>`, then why not take data directly from the list instead of taking it from the `RecyclerView` ?

Comment: Did you try to wrap it with <ScrollView> ?

Comment: i am not taking the data from the list because when list came every item has 4 edittexts and i have to fill it up and then save it to the database thats why any solution for that . @ZeekHuge

Comment: what will happen if i wrap it up with a scrollview

Comment: @SachinLatiyan Did you get any solution for this issue??

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for this.

Adapter has two methods

```
onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder){}
```

and

```
onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder){}
```

Create a **HashMap** in your adapter

```
public HashMap<Integer, RecyclerView.ViewHolder> holderHashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

and add holder into it in onDetach and remove the same onAttach. Like this.

```
 @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holderHashMap.put(holder.getAdapterPosition(),holder);
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        holderHashMap.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

    }
```

to access all viewHolders including the invisible ones use this in you activity.

```
for(int i =0; i<recyclerView.getItemCount();i++){
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = surveyQuestionList.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);

            if(holder == null){
                holder = adapter.holderHashMap.get(i);
            }
}
```

This is the best solution so far I have come up with.

Comment: I will try this i will tell you it works for me thank you by the way

Comment: @SachinLatiyan Cool .. Just accept the answer if it works for you.